# Why are there forty characters left over in Google's PEM for packing a Chrome extension

Tags: python, google-chrome-extension, rsa, pem, pycrypto

I've recently been trying to figure out how to get PyCrypto to recognize PEM's which are produced by Google Chrome's packing process.  The problem is that the standard importKey method causes errors.  After a rather long process, I finally realized that I can initially simulate the import by reverse-engineering the DerSequence.decode method (all of the details [here](http://www.allen-poole.com/wordpress/2011/01/how-to-import-a-google-chrome-pem-into-python/)).  Unfortunately, it leaves me with one issue unresolved.

I can get the key to import, and it looks like it's fairly consistent, but I have 40 characters left over.

```
import binascii

# read the pem file into chromepem
# the first and last lines are useless, 
# we need it to be a string, not a tuple 
# and it needs to be one string with no newlines.
chromepem = ''.join(open("chrome.pem","r").readlines()[1:-1]).replace("\n","")

# not sure why, but it looks like the first 40 characters aren't necessary.
# removing them seems to create a consistent public key anyway...
pem = binascii.a2b_base64(chromepem[40:])
```

Does anyone know why those 40 characters are there?  Will ignoring them cause issues with some private/public key pairs?

Comment: Have you tried simply using `RSA.ImportKey()`? You should need to do anything with the 1st and last lines, just read the whole thing in and give it to ImportKey.

Comment: I did.  It tells me that the key is improperly formatted.  TRUST ME, had I been able to do that I would have saved myself twenty hours of frustration.

Comment: ha, I trust you, but I had to ask. One problem is that PEM is not really a specific format per se but rather a general format that takes a binary blob, base64 encodes it, and surrounds it with BEGIN and END lines. Probably ImportKey expect one kind of binary blob and your PEM file is the other kind. There are three common private key formats in this situation, PKCS8, PKCS12, and openssl proprietary. Maybe later today I'll play around with the Google Chrome software and see if I can figure out which it is, and which PyCrypto RSA is looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, the simplest thing to do is to use the openssl rsa utiity to convert the chrome.pem file to a chrome.der file. Something like

```
openssl rsa -in chrome.pem -out chrome.der -outform DER
```

should do the trick. Now you can use the bytes from chrome.der directly in the `RSA.importKey()` method.

Comment: That's actually what the bash script does (and it works consistently).  I was hoping to have a pure Python implementation though.

Comment: Completely reasonable, I may yet figure something out. The pycrypto stuff looks a little sketchy on documentation and the API looks rather incomplete to me.

Comment: (It is VERY sketchy on documentation...)